# neuralnet: requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

Tags: r, matrix, neural-network

I used the package `neuralnet` to build a classification model in R. However, I encountered the famous error:

```
Error in cbind(1, pred) %*% weights [[num_hidden_layers + 1]]:    
requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
```

There are many other similar questions here, but none of them solved my problem. These are the steps I am taking:

1. Using `model.matrix` to create dummy columns (ensuring no column is factor or string)
2. Creating a manual formula by `paste` function
3. Training `neuralnet` using the one-hot-encoded dataset of step 1 and the formula created in step 2

Up to here, everything is fine. No error. The model converges after 5000 iterations. However, when I use either `compute` or `predict` functions to have a prediction on the test data, it gives me the above error.

I am pretty sure that the columns are the same and have the same name. Also, the class is numeric for each and every attribute. I told myself that maybe the test set is not transformed well using `model.matrix`, so I used the same training set in the predict/compute function! Surprisingly, it gives a similar error for the same training set! If the data is not a numeric/complex matrix, how is it trained at first and cannot be predicted now?

PS: I cannot share the data due to a privacy issue. This is the simplified code:

```
trainset = model.matrix(~., data=train_roig)
NN_model = neuralnet(f, trainset[,-c(1:2)], hidden = c(4,2))
# NO ERROR
compute(NN_model, trainset[,-c(1:2)])
# GIVES ME THE ERROR
predict(NN_model, trainset[,-c(1:2)])
# GIVES ME THE SAME ERROR
```

Double-checking column names:

```
NN_model$model.list$variables == colnames(trainset[,-c(1:2)])
# TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Checking structure of trainset after applying `model.matrix`:

```
str(trainset)
# num [1:134260, 1:19] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ... 
# -attr(*, "dimnames") = list of 2
# ..$ : chr [1:134260] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
# ..$ : chr [1:19] "Y" "n_trips" "age" "sexM" ...
```

Comment: You seem to have some syntax errors here. Things like missing `]` and `)`. Are you sure this is the code you are running? The error message sure make it sound like a data problem but if you are unable to share a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) it's going to be very difficult to help you.

Comment: @MrFlick As I was unable to copy-paste the code from the remote desktop, I typed them. That's the reason for the missing `)` or `]`. I fixed them here. They are correct there. This is a very specific issue and is not easy to create any other reproducible example for it. What other debugging steps you suggest? You mention a data problem. What exactly you mean by it?

Comment: What are the column data types involved? What does `str(trainset)` return? It seems to work with the sample in the help page `nn <- neuralnet(Species == "setosa" ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width, iris, hidden=c(4,2)); predict(nn, iris)` so how is your data different? Do you have any NA or infinite values? Try using `debugonce(neuralnet:::predict.nn)` to step through the code to see what's going on in the function

Comment: There is no NA value or infinite number.  iris dataset is a data frame; however, I used `model.matrix` to convert the factor columns to numeric. Therefore, the result of `str` function is a little bit weird. I added the result of `str` to my original question if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible issue is convergence. If the number of `stepmax` reaches but the default `threshold` does not meet, then the model will not generate any weight.

Use `plot(trainset)` to make sure your weights are generated. If it was unable to plot your network due to weight absence, then you need to increase the `threshold` or `stepmax` to let the model fit.

This issue happens only with `neuralnet`. Other functions I worked with, even if they do not converge, will give you the last weight before the final step. However, this package only releases weights if it converges.